# SQL query using code igniter

Tags: codeigniter

How can I write this query to a code igniter query?

```
WHERE
  SmallVersion.ID =
  (
    SELECT ChildSmallVersionID AS ID FROM SmallVersion
    WHERE ID = $id
  )
```

this is how is looks so far:

```
         ->where('SmallVersion.ID', ("SELECT `ChildSmallVersionID` AS ID
                  FROM `SmallVersion` WHERE ID = $id"));
```

Comment: you mean active record?

Comment: I'm trying to use the same query but in codeigniter format; I'm not sure how to write it and I can't get the records returned.

Comment: you mind sharing table schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mateusz Wojtula's answer looks ok but you can protect your query

```
$strSubQuery = $this->db
    ->select("ChildSmallVersionID AS ID")
    ->from("SmallVersion")
    ->where("ID",$id)
    ->get_compiled_select();

$where = "SmallVersion.ID = (".$strSubQuery.")";
$this->db->where($where, NULL, FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to create brackets in Active Records but you can write it directly in your clause:

```
$where = "SmallVersion.ID =
  (
    SELECT ChildSmallVersionID AS ID FROM SmallVersion
    WHERE ID = $id
  )";
$this->db->where($where, NULL, FALSE);
```

If third parameter is set to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not protect your query.

Documentation for active records:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

Answer (score 0):

if you want to apply this query

```
(
    SELECT ChildSmallVersionID AS ID FROM SmallVersion
    WHERE ID = $id
 )
```

can make pice of query

```
$this->db->group_start()->select('ChildSmallVersionID AS ID')->where('ID', $id)->group_end();
```

and let make this query to string

```
$_sub_query = $this->db->group_start()->select('ChildSmallVersionID AS ID FROM SmallVersion')->where('ID', $id)->group_end()->get_compiled_select('SmallVersion');
```

and apply like

```
->where('SmallVersion.ID', $_sub_query);
```